# Umbraco: Restoring content. Could not get parent with Id

Tags: umbraco, restore

I'm working on an Umbraco cloud project. I pulled the website from the git repositories and built it. First thing to do there when you run the site is to restore the content that's in the development environment to the local project so we can create new features. Yet Umbraco fails to do so with the following error:

```
The source environment has thrown a Umbraco.Deploy.Exceptions.ProcessArtifactException 
with message: Process pass #3 failed for artifact 
umb://document/xxthexguidxofxsomexpagexxxxxxxxx. It might have been 
caused by an inner Umbraco.Deploy.Exceptions.EnvironmentException with 
message: Could not get parent with id xxthexxx-guid-xofx-xthe-xxhomepagexx.

The following artifacts might be involved:

umb://document/xxthexxxguidxofxxthexxhomepagexx
The technical details may contain more information.
```

I've noticed that I some strange errors occur if not everything is deployed in the development site in the cloud. So I made sure everything is published.. Still errors though... I'm kinda lost here.

Has anyone come across simular issues? And how did you fix it?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Having the same issue. Curious if you found a resolution? :)

Comment: Managed to get my hands on an old copy of the sdf file. I stopped IIS. Deleted the umbraco.sdf file. Replaced it with the old database. Then I erased the version of umbraco in the web.config forcing it into upgrade mode. Then it somehow accepted that database. 

After that I had a database with a "Home" node in it which I could then restore.. Not too happy about that approach, but it worked...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a number of reasons, so it's a bit hard to say what exactly the problem is in your case.

Most of the time this happens due to either a circular reference of some sort causing a state that can't really be restored. For example that could be a datatype having a dependency on a node - but the node doesn't exist in a blank new environment. The content restore then refuses to start until the structural data (datatypes, contenttypes and such) is completely in sync, but the datatypes will never be able to be in sync until the content node exists. It's a sort of catch22 situation that might need to be resolved manually.

I would suggest you contact support through the Cloud portal and they will assist you in getting your problem resolved.

Comment: Hi Claus, Thanks for your answer. Thanks for your suggestion, I will deffenitely look into that. I did contact Umbraco. They proposed serveral resolutions and even sent me dlls. That didn't fix the problem though.. So I gave up and managed to hack my way around the problem..